# Create Sub-Projects based on main Git project.

Tags: git, version-control, web-deployment

I'm relatively new to Git since I only use it for basic operations(pull,commit,push). I have a main web project that I want to transform in my base library/project for future web developments.
The new pages/projects will take this base and implement their own contents being totally independent from each other and wont be necessarily be under version control(at least final page which is hosted with ftp only access), but if the main git project gets updated I would like sub-projects to get updated as well and there's where I think Git's magic comes to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the core, library, or boilerplate code as separate project.  You can include that code into the consuming projects as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

You could also make child projects fork the library, then be sure each child adds the library as an upstream remote, and pull the boilerplate that way. Read 'configure remotes' [here](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo), or ask the Goog.

Use .gitignore to keep things out of version control, though I don't think that would be necessary.